# Return none null entries with expression builder

Tags: ms-access, expressionbuilder

I have an excel table that has a column called "Wire", the column is marked "x" if a wire is present is my list of materials. I imported this table into Microsoft Access Web App. 
For primary data below. I want it to display any materials that don't have an X marked in the Wire column.. How do i write the expression for that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some kind of iif() expression will not filter a form (web based, or in plain old regular Access).

Simply build a query, and put in the query grid False for this column. (assuming it is a yes/no or true/false column).

Once you build the query then any form based on this query will return materials that have that column as false.